# What does "JNA: could not detach thread" mean and how to solve it?

Tags: java, jna, fuse

I am using [fuse-jna](https://github.com/EtiennePerot/fuse-jna) to implement a fuse filesystem in java. I have a working draft right now but when doing some operations like writing or reading files I continuously get the error

> "JNA: could not detach thread"

printed to the console. Writing / reading the data seems to work without problems.

Can anyone tell me what this error means and what may cause it? Can I ignore this or should I address this problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly innocuous.  What it means is that when a native thread exits, JNA attempts to detach from the JVM so that the JVM can dispose of any Java resources associated with the thread.  This may be because the JVM has already detached the native thread or for some other reason, and varies by JVM.